# What is the fastest way to multiply two 2D numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiplication

we are supposed to find a way to multiply a 2D array X of size (7403, 33) with its transpose

i mean this X* X.T

The solution is supposed to be 2.5 times faster than the np.dot(X,X.T). 
i have tried everything i can think of

```
%timeit np.dot(X,X.T)
%timeit np.matmul(X,X.T)
%timeit X@X.T
%timeit np.einsum("ij, jk -> ik",X,X.T)
```

and i have only acheived 1.5 times faster than the numpy dot

```
3.17 s ± 14.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
2.03 s ± 6.82 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
2.01 s ± 6.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
2.02 s ± 6.67 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Your `timeit` results suggest that the last 3 call the same procedure. Why do you need it to be faster?

Comment: @roganjosh we are learning numpy. so it is our test. I have tried everything i can think of. any suggestions?

Comment: I think you should start doing some analysis how the result will look like. Multiplying a matrix with its transpose has an interesting *structure*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i donot know how will that help. but looks like the determinant is 1. How does that help? Please explain?

Comment: if you guys could help. i would really appreciate it

Comment: The question and answer are puzzling.  What level of class is this?  Was it actually exploring `scipy.linalg.blas` and expecting you to find answers there?  I haven't used it, though I think I've seen one or two SO questions exploring that area.

Comment: @hpaulj we were taught a little of numpy and scipy. its a masters  degree level class. We were allowed to use libraries other than numpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i found the solution with scipy

```
%timeit np.dot(X,X.T)
%timeit np.matmul(X,X.T)
%timeit X@X.T
%timeit np.einsum("ij, jk -> ik",X,X.T)
%timeit linalg.blas.dgemm(alpha=1.0, a=X, b=X.T)
```

which gives

```
3.07 s ± 16.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
2.02 s ± 37.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
1.99 s ± 9.79 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
2 s ± 5.97 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
306 ms ± 6.85 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Can you explain why this answer is faster?

Comment: @hpaulj . i was hoping someone could explain this to mee. 
I believe it has got something to do with BLAS
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms

Comment: I haven't dug into this.  `dot` and so one tries to use BLAS or other standard libraries (`np.show_config()`).  My guess is that the `linalg.blas. ...` call is faster simply because it's a more direct call; there's less overhead and checking.  Read its docs.